# MySQL 5.6.21 on Debian 7.7 -- nice is automatically set to 19 several seconds after starting it up; can't figure out why

Tags: mysql, debian, vps, openvz, nice

I'm running MySQL 5.6.21 on an OpenVZ VPS with Debian 7.7. MySQL is installed from the DotDeb repository (full version number is 5.6.21-1~dotdeb.1).

Whenever the MySQL server is started or restarted, at first its niceness is 0. However, approximately 20 seconds later, it gets automatically reniced to 19 (lowest priority), and I can't figure out why.

I searched through all the configuration files, I verified that there are no cron jobs set to do this, and I looked through the startup script (/etc/init.d/mysql). There is nothing there that would be causing this.

If I manually renice it back to 0, sometimes it stays at 0, and sometimes it eventually gets reniced to 19 again.

It's not causing any performance issues for the websites hosted on this VPS (I have some very efficient caching in place which limits the need to even touch the database), but this little mystery is starting to get on my nerves. I'm a MySQL DBA by profession and have a MySQL 5.6 Database Administrator certification from Oracle, but I can't figure out this quirk...and it is very frustrating for me.

Sure, I could just set up an hourly cron job checking the niceness of the MySQL server process, and if it has changed, renice it back to 0, but I want to know why it is happening, not just slap a band-aid over it.

Any thoughts or assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

#### **/etc/mysql/my.cnf**

```
[client]
socket  = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

[mysqld_safe]
nice      = 0
socket    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
log_error = /var/log/mysql/mysql-error.log

[mysqld]
basedir                         = /usr
bind_address                    = 127.0.0.1
connect_timeout                 = 30
datadir                         = /var/lib/mysql
innodb_buffer_pool_size         = 224M
innodb_file_per_table           = 1
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit  = 2
innodb_log_buffer_size          = 4M
innodb_log_file_size            = 8M
innodb_open_files               = 2048
innodb_thread_concurrency       = 8
interactive_timeout             = 60
join_buffer_size                = 2M
key_buffer_size                 = 128K
log-queries-not-using-indexes   = 1
long_query_time                 = 2
max_allowed_packet              = 16M
max_connections                 = 125
max_connect_errors              = 100
max_heap_table_size             = 1M
pid_file                        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
query_cache_limit               = 8M
query_cache_min_res_unit        = 1K
query_cache_size                = 48M
query_cache_type                = 1
read_rnd_buffer_size            = 1M
skip_external_locking           = 1
slow_query_log                  = 1
slow_query_log_file             = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
socket                          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
sort_buffer_size                = 1M
table_definition_cache          = 2048
table_open_cache                = 2048
table_open_cache_instances      = 4
thread_cache_size               = 16
tmp_table_size                  = 1M
user                            = mysql
wait_timeout                    = 60

[mysqldump]
max_allowed_packet = 16M
quick
quote_names

[isamchk]
key_buffer = 128K

!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
```

#### **contents of config files in /etc/mysql/conf.d**

```
#
# The MySQL 5.6 database server configuration file.
#
# This custom MySQL 5.6 specific configuration file
# adds on top of the existing default my.cnf file at
# - /etc/mysql/my.cnf.
#
# Please add any extra MySQL 5.6 options in this file
# for sake of clarity.
#
# You may uncomment any existing option to enable it
#
# sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES

[mysqld_safe]
syslog
```

#### **/etc/init.d/mysql**

```
#!/bin/bash
#
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          mysql
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $syslog
# Should-Start:      $network $time
# Should-Stop:       $network $time
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Start and stop the mysql database server daemon
# Description:       Controls the main MySQL database server daemon "mysqld"
#                    and its wrapper script "mysqld_safe".
### END INIT INFO
#
set -e
set -u
${DEBIAN_SCRIPT_DEBUG:+ set -v -x}

test -x /usr/bin/mysqld_safe || exit 0

. /lib/lsb/init-functions

SELF=$(cd $(dirname $0); pwd -P)/$(basename $0)
CONF=/etc/mysql/my.cnf
MYADMIN="/usr/bin/mysqladmin --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/debian.cnf"

# priority can be overriden and "-s" adds output to stderr
ERR_LOGGER="logger -p daemon.err -t /etc/init.d/mysql -i"

# Safeguard (relative paths, core dumps..)
cd /
umask 077

# mysqladmin likes to read /root/.my.cnf. This is usually not what I want
# as many admins e.g. only store a password without a username there and
# so break my scripts.
export HOME=/etc/mysql/

## Fetch a particular option from mysql's invocation.
#
# Usage: void mysqld_get_param option
mysqld_get_param() {
    /usr/sbin/mysqld --print-defaults \
        | tr " " "\n" \
        | grep -- "--$1" \
        | tail -n 1 \
        | cut -d= -f2
}

## Do some sanity checks before even trying to start mysqld.
sanity_checks() {
  # check for config file
  if [ ! -r /etc/mysql/my.cnf ]; then
    log_warning_msg "$0: WARNING: /etc/mysql/my.cnf cannot be read. See README.Debian.gz"
    echo                "WARNING: /etc/mysql/my.cnf cannot be read. See README.Debian.gz" | $ERR_LOGGER
  fi

  # check for diskspace shortage
  datadir=`mysqld_get_param datadir`
  if LC_ALL=C BLOCKSIZE= df --portability $datadir/. | tail -n 1 | awk '{ exit ($4>4096) }'; then
    log_failure_msg "$0: ERROR: The partition with $datadir is too full!"
    echo                "ERROR: The partition with $datadir is too full!" | $ERR_LOGGER
    exit 1
  fi
}

## Checks if there is a server running and if so if it is accessible.
#
# check_alive insists on a pingable server
# check_dead also fails if there is a lost mysqld in the process list
#
# Usage: boolean mysqld_status [check_alive|check_dead] [warn|nowarn]
mysqld_status () {
    ping_output=`$MYADMIN ping 2>&1`; ping_alive=$(( ! $? ))

    ps_alive=0
    pidfile=`mysqld_get_param pid-file`
    if [ -f "$pidfile" ] && ps `cat $pidfile` >/dev/null 2>&1; then ps_alive=1; fi

    if [ "$1" = "check_alive"  -a  $ping_alive = 1 ] ||
       [ "$1" = "check_dead"   -a  $ping_alive = 0  -a  $ps_alive = 0 ]; then
    return 0 # EXIT_SUCCESS
    else
    if [ "$2" = "warn" ]; then
        echo -e "$ps_alive processes alive and '$MYADMIN ping' resulted in\n$ping_output\n" | $ERR_LOGGER -p daemon.debug
    fi
    return 1 # EXIT_FAILURE
    fi
}

#
# main()
#

case "${1:-''}" in
  'start')
    sanity_checks;
    # Start daemon
    log_daemon_msg "Starting MySQL database server" "mysqld"
    if mysqld_status check_alive nowarn; then
       log_progress_msg "already running"
       log_end_msg 0
    else
        # Could be removed during boot
        test -e /var/run/mysqld || install -m 755 -o mysql -g root -d /var/run/mysqld

        # Start MySQL!
        su - mysql -s /bin/sh -c "/usr/bin/mysqld_safe > /dev/null 2>&1 &"

        # 6s was reported in #352070 to be too few when using ndbcluster
        # 14s was reported in #736452 to be too few with large installs
        for i in $(seq 1 30); do
                sleep 1
            if mysqld_status check_alive nowarn ; then break; fi
        log_progress_msg "."
        done
        if mysqld_status check_alive warn; then
                log_end_msg 0
            # Now start mysqlcheck or whatever the admin wants.
            output=$(/etc/mysql/debian-start)
        [ -n "$output" ] && log_action_msg "$output"
        else
            log_end_msg 1
        log_failure_msg "Please take a look at the syslog"
        fi
    fi
    ;;

  'stop')
    # * As a passwordless mysqladmin (e.g. via ~/.my.cnf) must be possible
    # at least for cron, we can rely on it here, too. (although we have
    # to specify it explicit as e.g. sudo environments points to the normal
    # users home and not /root)
    log_daemon_msg "Stopping MySQL database server" "mysqld"
    if ! mysqld_status check_dead nowarn; then
      set +e
      shutdown_out=`$MYADMIN shutdown 2>&1`; r=$?
      set -e
      if [ "$r" -ne 0 ]; then
        log_end_msg 1
        [ "$VERBOSE" != "no" ] && log_failure_msg "Error: $shutdown_out"
        log_daemon_msg "Killing MySQL database server by signal" "mysqld"
        killall -15 mysqld
            server_down=
        for i in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10; do
              sleep 1
              if mysqld_status check_dead nowarn; then server_down=1; break; fi
            done
          if test -z "$server_down"; then killall -9 mysqld; fi
      fi
        fi

        if ! mysqld_status check_dead warn; then
      log_end_msg 1
      log_failure_msg "Please stop MySQL manually and read /usr/share/doc/mysql-server-5.6/README.Debian.gz!"
      exit -1
    else
      log_end_msg 0
        fi
    ;;

  'restart')
    set +e; $SELF stop; set -e
    $SELF start
    ;;

  'reload'|'force-reload')
    log_daemon_msg "Reloading MySQL database server" "mysqld"
    $MYADMIN reload
    log_end_msg 0
    ;;

  'status')
    if mysqld_status check_alive nowarn; then
      log_action_msg "$($MYADMIN version)"
    else
      log_action_msg "MySQL is stopped."
      exit 3
    fi
    ;;

  *)
    echo "Usage: $SELF start|stop|restart|reload|force-reload|status"
    exit 1
    ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like it may be set in `mysqld_safe`. [**There was once an ancient bug about this**](http://lists.mysql.com/mysql/28170).

Recall the [mysqld_safe](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqld-safe.html) calls [mysqld](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqld.html) from within an indefinite loop.

Goto the OS and run the following:

```
grep -n nice `which mysqld_safe`
```

This will show you all places where nice is set, defaulted and used

I just ran this on a CentOS VM that's running MySQL 5.5.20

```
[~]# cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS release 5.7 (Final)
[~]# mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.20, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1
[~]# grep -n nice `which mysqld_safe`
17:niceness=0
56:  --nice=NICE                Set the scheduling priority of mysqld
200:      --nice=*) niceness="$val" ;;
629:if test $niceness -eq 0
633:  NOHUP_NICENESS="nohup nice -$niceness"
636:# Using nice with no args to get the niceness level is GNU-specific.
638:# BSD could use "nohup sh -c 'ps -o nice -p $$' | tail -1").
641:if nohup nice > /dev/null 2>&1
643:    normal_niceness=`nice`
644:    nohup_niceness=`nohup nice 2>/dev/null`
646:    numeric_nice_values=1
647:    for val in $normal_niceness $nohup_niceness
654:                numeric_nice_values=0 ;;
658:    if test $numeric_nice_values -eq 1
660:        nice_value_diff=`expr $nohup_niceness - $normal_niceness`
661:        if test $? -eq 0 && test $nice_value_diff -gt 0 && \
662:            nice --$nice_value_diff echo testing > /dev/null 2>&1
667:            niceness=`expr $niceness - $nice_value_diff`
668:            NOHUP_NICENESS="nice -$niceness nohup"
```

See if the first occurrence of nice (in this case niceness) is set to 19.

You could also just grep for the number 19 in the [**mysqld_safe script**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqld-safe.html).

I have never heard of random setting of niceness before. Nevertheless, I would start with [**mysqld_safe**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqld-safe.html)

Keep in mind that mysqld may have been launched as a nohup with niceness.

According to [**Wikipedia on nice**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nice_(Unix))

> nice is a program found on Unix and Unix-like operating systems such as Linux. It directly maps to a kernel call of the same name. nice is used to invoke a utility or shell script with a particular priority, thus giving the process more or less CPU time than other processes. A niceness of −20 is the highest priority and 19 or 20 is the lowest priority. The default niceness for processes is inherited from its parent process and is usually 0.

Note the last sentence

> The default niceness for processes is inherited from its parent process and is usually 0.

This sounds disturbing because mysqld could possibly be re-inheriting its original nice value. Who is the parent of [mysqld](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqld.html)? Like I said in the beginning: it's [mysqld_safe](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqld-safe.html).

You should also make sure your OS is not running with 19 for nice. Simply run nice to find out.

Also, note the usage message for nice

```
[~]# nice --help
Usage: nice [OPTION] [COMMAND [ARG]...]
Run COMMAND with an adjusted niceness, which affects process scheduling.
With no COMMAND, print the current niceness.  Nicenesses range from
-20 (most favorable scheduling) to 19 (least favorable).

  -n, --adjustment=N   add integer N to the niceness (default 10)
      --help     display this help and exit
      --version  output version information and exit

NOTE: your shell may have its own version of nice, which usually supersedes
the version described here.  Please refer to your shell's documentation
for details about the options it supports.**

Report bugs to <bug-coreutils@gnu.org>.
```

Based on the aforementioned `NOTE:`, your shell's nice may have an issue. If [mysqld_safe](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqld-safe.html) inherits its niceness from above, [mysqld](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqld.html) will be [**grandfathered with the grandparent's niceness**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C6MnK2DxEp8).

Comment: Thanks so much for all this information. Unfortunately nothing there is setting the niceness for MySQL. niceness=0 in the first test (and the rest of the output matches yours), and grepping mysqld_safe for '19' just returns a comment with a copyright dated 1996. Running 'nice' with no arguments or options returns 0.

Any other thoughts?

Thanks again!